# Odoo mobile sync does not work

Tags: java, android, synchronization, odoo

I downloaded the odoo framework from the github, I installed it and locally every thing is working just fine,  But it does not sync with the server no records came from the server and none go, It just work locally
I have seen the issues part in the github, but i does't give so much help
Is there any one knows what exaclly the problem?? Or any one have working copy of the framework??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but syncing worked fine after commenting out the some lines out of the file ContentResolver.java: search for lines 2326, 2327, 2328

```
 public static void setMasterSyncAutomatically(boolean sync) {
 setMasterSyncAutomaticallyAsUser(sync, UserHandle.myUserId());
 }
```

change them to:

```
 //  public static void setMasterSyncAutomatically(boolean sync) {
 //  setMasterSyncAutomaticallyAsUser(sync, UserHandle.myUserId());
 // }
```

I know this is not the correct way to do it, because you seem to override the authorisation check, but for me, for now, and for testing purposes it works.
(hope it helps, please don't shoot me)